# how to get shared image from facebook app in android

Tags: android, facebook, image, share

my app in android wants to get image from facebook app, i use this code and it work fine in other app (like galley & firefox &...) but when share photo from facebook app to my app my app force close and not work, how to solve it ?

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        } 
    }
void handleSendImage(Intent intent) { 
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    photoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        selectedPath = getPath(imageUri);
        Uri u = Uri.parse(selectedPath);
        File f = new File("" + u);
        filename=f.getName();
        if(f.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            photoView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Crash report? Exception details? Logcat report?

Comment: Use FacebookDialog to Share Someting on Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: my dear, i want image facebook app share to my app?

Comment: plz show in a code !how to get image from facebook app to my app